# kubernetes services remains in termination state,after deleting them

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

[image: see the image]

commands used are: 1) kubectl delete svc service-name
2) kubectl delete svc service-name --grace-period=0 --force

Above commands results in stuck of termination phase...

Comment: Is your cluster integrated with some kind of IAAS, some cloud-controller in any namespace? If so, this could suggest that IAAS is purging the corresponding resources. Or is this bare-metal? If so: are you using MetalLB? Quick answer, there could be several reasons for this, some context could help.

Comment: I am using AKS , Azure subscription

Comment: You could check `kubectl get events`, and look for some "cloud-controller-manager" pod and check its logs: there's probably something wrong between this and the Azure API.

Comment: How do those services look like when you run `kubectl get svc` ? Then you can also describe them e.g. `kubectl describe svc <svc_name>`. Anything in the `Events` section ?